# How to add parameters to a GitHub API request via cURL?

Tags: rest, curl, github-api

I’m trying to access the GitHub API using a cURL request and having trouble adding a couple parameters.

Currently this is working:

```
curl \                    
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/sspboyd/Presidential_Debates/commits >> output.json
```

I want to use the page= and per_page=100 parameters as listed here:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits

I have tried using `?page=1` and `/?page=1` as shown below and neither of these work:

```
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/sspboyd/Presidential_Debates/commits?page=1 >> output.json
```

```
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/sspboyd/Presidential_Debates/commits/?page=1 >> output.json
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: And, strangely, when I put just the URL into a browser it works fine...   

`https://api.github.com/repos/sspboyd/Presidential_Debates/commits?page=1`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/sspboyd/Presidential_Debates/commits?page=1" 
 >> output.json
```

Note the double quotes on the URL.

I was running into a similar issue with the Github api. I then figured out it was a problem with special characters in the url. In this case the `?` is causing the problem.